# Could not able to checkout code from github in spring tools suite 4.11.1

Tags: spring-tools-4

I tried to checkout code from github through spring tool suite, it does not connect to github. Keep asking user name and password.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what have you been doing and how you attempted to achieve that. Also check that it is not related to the new github authentication policy, which is in place only for a couple of days/weeks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.